# Creating a stitched scene using glFrustum

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, graphics, 3d

I have a program in which I can make a scene render on a screen as per the user's position. As the user changes position, the frustum changes to give off-axis projection. I want to utilize the technique to work on three different displays stitching together a bigger scene, with something of the following sort:

[image]
Imagine a big real world scene rendered across the three displays. The three displays should be showing the scene as it would look with a changed perspective on each display as per the position of the user. I am able to do this with one display to render a scene as per user's position, but unable to think of the method for this to work on three screens.

The class off-axis projection that I have created basically does the following:

```
customCam::project(){
pushMatrices();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
        glFrustum(leftNear.x, rightNear.x, bottomNear.y, topNear.y, _near, _far);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(uPos.x, uPos.y, 0, uPos.x, uPos.y, -1, 0, 1, 0); //neglect z scaling for now. In the main program, it's there
    glTranslatef(0, 0, uPos.z);
}
```

How do I stich the three frustum in such a fashion that the scene looks continuous as in real world? Currently, a user of the class draws a scene as follows:

```
cstCam.project();
    //draw something here
popMatriceS(); //which were pushed before glFrustum projection
```

**EDIT:**
In my case, to define three frustums for a user (taking into accoutn user and screen corners for all displays in the same frame of reference), I did the following:

```
custCam1.project();
//draw scene here. eg: two walls at the far left and right screen
drawWalls();
popMatrices();
custCam2.project();
drawWalls();
popMatrices();
custCam3.project();
drawWalls();
popMatrices();

void drawWalls(){
//Left most corner screen wall
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-1.5*PHWIDTH, HEIGHT/2, 0); //where PHWIDTH, HEIGHT is the physical width/height of each screen
glVertex3f(-1.5*PHWIDTH, HEIGHT/2, -50);
glVertex3f(-1.5*PHWIDTH, -HEIGHT/2, -50);
glVertex3f(-1.5*PHWIDTH, -HEIGHT/2, 0);
glEnd();

//Right most corner screen wall
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(1.5*PHWIDTH, HEIGHT/2, 0); //where PHWIDTH, HEIGHT is the physical width/height of each screen
glVertex3f(1.5*PHWIDTH, HEIGHT/2, -50);
glVertex3f(1.5*PHWIDTH, -HEIGHT/2, -50);
glVertex3f(1.5*PHWIDTH, -HEIGHT/2, 0);
glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not that difficult as it might look. Consider the following image (the three screens looked at from above at the znear level)

[image: Screens from above]

I assumed that each screen spans 2 units in the x-direction at the znear distance. You may have to scale this value depending on your scene.

The range for the y-coordinate does not change for the three screens, because they are at the same vertical position.

So you need three different projection matrices for the screens. Determining the offset is pretty simple. You just need the differences to the camera point:

```
left screen   => [-3 - camera.x, -1 - camera.x]
center screen => [-1 - camera.x, 1 - camera.x]
right screen  => [1 - camera.x, 3 - camera.x]
```

Of course, you need the camera position in the screens' space as in the figure.

The view matrix can be an arbitrary one, but should be the same for all three screens. This time, pass the camera position in scene space to `gluLookAt`.

Comment: I editted my post to add a little bit of more detail of what I was able to achieve. I was basically able to find the offsets of all corners of screens from the user's position and then using my `cstCam::project` function defined three different projection matrices for these three screens. Using the code that I posted in the edit above, I tried simulating the same on my screen (three different viewports) and got the following results: 1) User in the centre of three screens http://i.imgur.com/u9O65G8.png ,2) User moves towards right: http://i.imgur.com/6bxY0R3.png

Comment: In the second screenshot that you would see, when the user moves towards the right, the wall from the first camera starts getting shown in the second screen and it does not form a continuos scene. However, what I am not sure is if this has something to do view matrix being the same in those three scenes as I did above? Also, if that is the case, I am not able to discern as to why there should be only one modelview matrix for all three. Would be great to read an explanation from your side on the same.

Comment: There should be only one (model)view matrix, becuase there is only one point of view, the eye point is identical in all three cases. Your viewing direction is also identical for each of the displays (perpendicular to the display plane, so just defining an asymmetric frustum per screen is all you need to do. Your screenshots suggest that you do not do it right...

Comment: @derhass: For single display, the assymetric frustum and the projection comes out to be correct as it seems. The code that I use for the same is http://pastebin.com/kLs6yGQA Here `begin` and `end` are the methods to use the camera, and I use the camera for the projection as `camera1.begin();` `//drawing` `camera1.end`. Since it works for a single display, the same code can be used for three displays in essence as I wrote the code for it in the edit. I am assuming since it worked for a single disp., there's somethin wrong happenin when I do with three but not sure if it's frustum or MV matrix?

Comment: @user1240679: Well, just show the real code you are using, and especially the values for the various parameters. It is hard to guess what is going on just from those code snippets.

Comment: @derhass: Sure. I am using a framework which uses OpenGL at the core but you can ignore that (provides abstraction for my purpose to avoid going into OpenGL intricacies). Here's the class where I am creating and using the three display windows: **.h file** http://pastebin.com/QUfFqhSP, **.cpp file** http://pastebin.com/dRdtNjw2 and the camera class itself that I created for assymetric frustum **.cpp** http://pastebin.com/M7e0vZHf

Comment: Your `gluLookAt` call doesn't seem to be the same for the three cameras. Just output the real values to a console and see where the problem might be.

Comment: @NicoSchertler : Apologies if it sounds OpenGL n00bish. Assume that I remove the gluLookAt function from my camera class. Does that mean, I would have to do `camera1.begin(); camera2.begin(); camera3.begin(); //common gluLookAt function camera1.end(); camera1.end(); camera1.end();` I would be creating three projection matrices all together (notice each camera is not ending after the second begin unlike what I  am doing currently), right? Also, it would be really helpful if you could provide a beginner kinda explanation as to why different MV matrices are making the difference here

Comment: @user1240679: you should be aware that your `camera.begin()` function actually does set a modelview matrix via `gluLookAt()`. It does so in a overcomplicated way, and, if I followed the code correctly, setting the position just wrong. If I read it correctly, it will only work by accident if you specify right=-left and top=-bottom for the corners of `SetViewPortalWindow`

Comment: @derhass : I checked again by removing other viewports and using only a single camera for one scene. The view portal I used this time was (Top Left: `-205.0,-71.0,0.0`, Top Right: `205.0,-71.0,0.0`, Bottom Left: `-205.0,-299.0,0.0`, Bottom Right: `205.0,-299.0,0.0`) and it worked for me. It would be great if you could point out the correct way to do the same since till this point I happened to use it only at this fixed position, hence not discovering this till this point.

Comment: @user1240679: well. I'm not sure that I understand the code correctly (have not thought about it deeply). You should simply set camera position to `_wcUserHead` (maybe with flipped z, not sure about your coord setup), and use some vector perpendicular to the display planes as viewing vector. YOur code seems to somehow end up setting  somehting like `-(_wcMidScreen - _wcUserHead)` (for x and y, you separately handle z) as camera position, obscuring this fact by projecting this point repeatedly onto near plane and display plane.

Comment: @derhass : `wcMidScreen - wcUserHead` was done to calculate by how much amount the user has moved from the position of a symmetric frustum. By calculating the amount of shift from the centre of the screen (where the frustum would have been symmetric) and scaling it with z value of the user, I change the camera position. If I just set it as wcUserHead, do you mean I should also let the corners be straightway _wcTopLeft, wcTopRight etc. and not converting them into cam coordinates (i.e. `_camTopLeftScreen/_camTopLeftNear` , `_camBottomRightScreen/_camBottomRightNear`?

Comment: @user1240679: no. the frustum values seem correct to me. The are always specified relative to the camera position (or, more precisiley, specified in eye space), so you have to take the camera position into account. I don't know why you want to further correct the camera position. You always want to render from the point of view of the user. So you must place your camera there.

Comment: @derhass : Thanks. I'll check a little later by modifying the camera class to have `gluLookAt(_wcUserHead.x, _wcUserHead.y, 0, _wcUserHead.x, _wcUserHead.y, -1)` to see if it gives the correct results. But what about the z scaling with user's position?
2) About the original ques.: By creating another camera class where the begin method does not have `gluLookAt`, I'll try doing `camera1.begin(); camera2.begin()` //do gluLook for both together here `camera1.end(); camera2.end()` to have single MV matrix for multiple displays. I hope I understood these correctly but will let you know

Comment: @user1240679: Doing `camera1.begin(); camera2.begin(); gluLookAt(); camera1.end(); camera2.end()` does not make sense at all. You will just use camera2. The fact that you might have lying some other projection matrix somewhere on the matrix stack will not magically make it work. You cannot render with two different projection matrices at the same time (at least not with fixed-function GL).

Comment: @derhass : But Nico Schertler pointed out above that I would need to use three different projection matrices for three different screens. Does that mean I have to do it similarl to my current solution: `camera1.begin()` glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); gluLookAt(...); `camera1.end()` and similarly with `camera2` and `camera3`? But that contrasts for me to with what you just said above: `You will just use camera2`. Basically, how do I keep a single MV matrix for all three different projections in this case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31809/discussion-between-derhass-and-user1240679)